# Database connectivity issue in my code

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!

The connection is established.

The statement object is created.

Exception in thread "main" `java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object`

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:743)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:207)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:946)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1169)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdateInternal(OracleStatement.java:1615)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdate(OracleStatement.java:1580)
at conn1.main(conn1.java:17)
```

I am having no error in the code but still, I'm not able to make a table.

Comment: You need to provide your code also. It's not clear from just the exception

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14602960/java-sql-sqlsyntaxerrorexception-ora-00955-name-is-already-used-by-an-existing

Comment: **[edit]** your question and show us the code that runs the SQL statement generating the exception. But in general the error is pretty clear: you are creating an object with a name that is already taken - what exactly that is, is impossible to answer with seeing the SQL code

Comment: Not being able to create a table and connectivity are two different things. It would be a database connectivity issue if you could not log in. Since the error says the table already exists, clearly you can connect.

Answer (score 0):

**ORA-00955** name is already used by an existing object.

The table name that you are trying to create by using you code also already exists so try with some other name

Comment: i m trying with different names even.

Comment: please post you code so that we can find out exact issue